# how to configure aws instance store lifetime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am writing an app using Node. I tried to stream a remote resource to s3 without success. After search around, I realized this is probably not an achievable mission. Then I am going to save the remote resource to folder TMP before I can upload to S3.

Questions:

1. This TMP will be EC2 instance store? (app is still under dev
   localhost)
2. How to configure instance Store's life time? Or files need to be
   deleted manually(by API)?
   Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to stream data to S3 using multipart uploads (e.g. node package: s3-upload-stream). When you stop or terminate an EC2 instance, its instance store is wiped.

Comment: From document examples, s3-upload-stream does the same way: it stream a big file from server before upload to s3. What I need to do is to stream a file from URL  then pipe to s3, without saving to server temporarily. Thank you any way.

Comment: You can do that too. All S3 SDKs support the upload of byte arrays from memory buffers. No need to persist to file first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you might actually want to look into attaching an extra EBS to your instance, [Attaching EBS Volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html), or just modifying your existing instance and unchecking *Delete on Termination* under the storage tab [Preserving Volumes on Termination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/terminating-instances.html#preserving-volumes-on-termination):

[image]

As to how to configure the lifetime, you could look into AWS Lambda; with Lambda, you could potentially configure a script to run on a schedule that cleans up whatever data you need to remove.

If you find that you have to use the instance store for your situation, the lifetime is only configurable at launch, and data is not persisted across reboots. While the data is temporary, consider the possibility that something could happen while the data is in transit.